# Implementing Python methods in batch by casting

Tags: python

I have a Python class `Foo` and a more memory-conscious version `LightFoo`. The information contained in their attributes is ultimately the same but is encoded differently.

A handful of `Foo`'s methods will be completely re-written for `LightFoo`, but for most of them it will be fine to cast the `LightFoo` instance to a `Foo` and call the corresponding `Foo` method. For example, `LightFoo` might include:

```
def total(self):
    self.fooize().total()
```

If `Foo` has 100 methods, though, this gets really tedious. What would be really convenient is to set up `LightFoo` to inherit from `Foo` and have the casting step somehow inserted by default for all methods not found in `LightFoo`. I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but it seems like there must be a better approach than writing a block like the one above for each of `Foo`'s methods.

Comment: If `LightFoo` inherits from `Foo`, then any methods you don't define in `LightFoo` will automatically default to `Foo`. Is that not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fooize() is doing some custom processing to convert the object to a Foo, you can do this by just defining `__getattr__`, which is called when you access an attribute that can't be found. You can call `fooize()` there.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.fooize(), name)
```

Otherwise, you can just inherit from Foo and let the nonexistent methods fall back to the superclass.